# How can I avoid repetitions in Prolog results?

Tags: prolog, rules

I am wrinting a program in prolog and I have the next code:

```
isa(dumbo, smallelephant).
isa(cuatropataspequeñas, extremidad).
isa(cuatropatas, extremidad).
isa(trompa, cabeza).
isa(smallelephant, elephant).
isa(elephant, animal).

subclass(Class, Sup) :- isa(Class, Sup).
subclass(Class, Sup) :- isa(Class, Midclass), subclass(Midclass, Sup).

partOf(head, animal).
partOf(tip, animal).
partOf(t1, smallelephant).
partOf(t2, elephant).
partOf(h1, elephant).

hasPart(Object, Part) :- partOf(Part, Object).

hasPart(Object, Part) :- subclass(Object, Class), hasPart(Class, Part), not(is(_,Part)).
```

With these facts and rules the result I obtain when I execute "hasPart(dumbo, X)." is the next:

```
?- hasPart(dumbo, X).
X = t1;
X = t2;
X = h1;
X = t2;
X = h1;
false.
```

But I only want to get t1, t2 and t3. How could I do it?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Definition of the `tieneParte/2` predicate? Maybe you mean to write `hasPart/2`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `not(is(_,Part))` is **not** what you want to express: I guess you rather want to use `isa/2`. As (bad) luck would have it, `(is)/2` is a predefined predicate...

Comment: Isn't this a repeat of your other question? And I assume `is(_, Part)` really is supposed to be `isa(_, Part)`?

Comment: I think you need to define succinctly what the rule is. When you want to check parts of superclasses of the object, how far up do you want to go? In your example, you're wanting to go 2 levels (one to get past the isa and then one more). Is it always limit 2? Or do you have some other categorization for higher level classes which needs to be defined? Also, you predicate has termination issues: it goes into a stack overflow after finding the solutions. Check your circular definition for subclass. It's typically a good idea to make the predicate name different than the fact to help separate.